# multiple (my and 3rd-party) native libraries in Android NDK

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, native, eclipse-cdt, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have to use two native libraries: one is my own and the other one is 3rd-party. As long as I used them in separate projects, everything was ok. But now I'm getting the `Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

I'm using Eclipse.

I found out that if I place the existing library in libs/armeabi, Eclipse begins compilation of the native code and it fails. If I rebuild the JNI part from the command line, compilation succeeds but the 3rd party library disappears. Really stupid.

So how do I tell Eclipse to use an existing .so library along with a library that must be built? The libraries are independent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NDK allows for linking with prebuilt user libraries, using the PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY variable.

Assuming that the library you need to link is librandom.so, create a `libs` folder in `jni` subfolder of the project folder:

```
mkdir -p jni/libs
cp librandom.so jni/libs
```

Then, just create a `jni/libs/Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := random
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := librandom.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

You can create a section for each prebuilt library, all placed in `jni/libs`.

Next, you just need to include the above file into your jni/Android.mk to get things to work. In the NDK docs, it is recommended that this be done at the end of the Android.mk, rather than the middle:

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/Android.mk
```

However, you'll need to do this before the module that requires this library.

For linking, you'll need to add the following into the module section that links to the prebuilt library.

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := random
```

Then when you do ndk-build, it will copy this library into `libs/armeabi/` before building the module, and you're good to go.

Note: This does not solve problems with required headers. You'll still need to add the location of the headers for the library into the variable `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` in the module that requires it.

Comment: UPDATE: if one library depends on another, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688327/android-ndk-make-two-native-shared-libraries-calling-each-other

Comment: How can I include libraries that I only have the .so file and not the source code to?

Comment: We need a video explanation for the steps above, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have done for the moment. I will not accept (in stackoverflow sense) my own (this) answer beause it is unsatisfactory.

I have created a new project and copied all java files there. Then, I copied the .so library from the old project and the 3rd party library into libs/armeabi.

That's monstrous. But it works. For the moment. The worst thing is that the version control is torpedoed.