# replace a function in a .so file

Tags: android, gcc, java-native-interface, arm, shared-libraries

**WHY:**
I have a 3-party Android shared library (no source), libxyz.so, and the dalvik vm says `JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1) in` *filepath*. I assume that the vm is right and that function indeed returns this wrong value instead of a valid one. (As I understand, until now this was ignored because `debuggable` was set to true in the AndroidManifest.xml).

**HOW DO I** replace a function in the .so library by a function from another .so library?

(Not sure if I have to call the old function, in the general case yes, in my case probably no, but an advice how to call the old function would be appreciated too.)

```
00023da0 <JNI_OnLoad>:
   23da0:   e52de004    push    {lr}        ; (str lr, [sp, #-4]!)
   23da4:   e59f3094    ldr r3, [pc, #148]  ; 23e40 <JNI_OnLoad+0xa0>
   23da8:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
   23dac:   e28d1008    add r1, sp, #8
   23db0:   e3a02000    mov r2, #0
   23db4:   e5212004    str r2, [r1, #-4]!
   23db8:   e08f3003    add r3, pc, r3
   23dbc:   e3a02801    mov r2, #65536  ; 0x10000
   23dc0:   e583000c    str r0, [r3, #12]
   23dc4:   e2822004    add r2, r2, #4
   23dc8:   e5903000    ldr r3, [r0]
   23dcc:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
   23dd0:   e593f018    ldr pc, [r3, #24]
   23dd4:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
   23dd8:   0a000002    beq 23de8 <JNI_OnLoad+0x48>
   23ddc:   e3e00000    mvn r0, #0
   23de0:   e28dd00c    add sp, sp, #12
   23de4:   e8bd8000    pop {pc}
   23de8:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
   23dec:   e59f2050    ldr r2, [pc, #80]   ; 23e44 <JNI_OnLoad+0xa4>
   23df0:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   23df4:   e79f1002    ldr r1, [pc, r2]
   23df8:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
   23dfc:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
   23e00:   e593f018    ldr pc, [r3, #24]
   23e04:   e2501000    subs    r1, r0, #0
   23e08:   0afffff3    beq 23ddc <JNI_OnLoad+0x3c>
   23e0c:   e59d3004    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
   23e10:   e59f2030    ldr r2, [pc, #48]   ; 23e48 <JNI_OnLoad+0xa8>
   23e14:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
   23e18:   e593c000    ldr ip, [r3]
   23e1c:   e08f2002    add r2, pc, r2
   23e20:   e3a03033    mov r3, #51 ; 0x33
   23e24:   e1a0e00f    mov lr, pc
   23e28:   e59cf35c    ldr pc, [ip, #860]  ; 0x35c
   23e2c:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0
   23e30:   a3a00801    movge   r0, #65536  ; 0x10000
   23e34:   a2800004    addge   r0, r0, #4
   23e38:   aaffffe8    bge 23de0 <JNI_OnLoad+0x40>
   23e3c:   eaffffe6    b   23ddc <JNI_OnLoad+0x3c>
   23e40:   00103d6c    andseq  r3, r0, ip, ror #26
   23e44:   00103204    andseq  r3, r0, r4, lsl #4
   23e48:   00103a84    andseq  r3, r0, r4, lsl #21
```

Comment: If you can dump the so file and share JNI_OnLoad part, may be someone can show you how that can be modified.

Comment: Try something like `$ android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -d libxyz.so | grep JNI_OnLoad -A 20`

Comment: To be honest, I do not see where -1 may come from.

Comment: 23ddc:   e3e00000    mvn r0, #0
   23de0:   e28dd00c    add sp, sp, #12
   23de4:   e8bd8000    pop {pc}

Comment: mvn = move not, not of 0 = ff, -1?

Comment: two things: JNI_OnLoad returns ERR (-1), not the wrong value and inside it calls some other functions. It actually returns because first function doesn't return 0. `23dd4:   e3500000    cmp r0, #0 23dd8:   0a000002    beq 23de8 <JNI_OnLoad+0x48>`. You can get wild in many ways here, immediately return at the top, remove/disable the compare with 0 after first function. up to you. but probably these things might shot you back in the leg later on.

Comment: In my cookbook, `JNI_OnLoad()` is either missing, or it has very important things to accomplish. In the later case, if it returns before all its job is done (whether with error code or without), it is not wise to continue as if nothing wrong happened.

Answer (score 0):

What it was:

as *@auselen* absolutely correctly wrote, the function failed to initialize and therefore returned -1. Namely, it needed to access by name some inner classes of the class that contained the native functions.

I used the following proguard spell:

```
-keep public class com.xyz.abc.XYZ
-keepclassmembers class com.xyz.adc.XYZ { *; }
-keep class com.xyz.abc.XYZ$* { *; }
```

Many thanks to *@auselen*!

EDIT: meanwhile, I once again face a problem of this sort.
`objcopy` has `--redefine-sym`, but somewhy it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although in one case I could avoid solving this problem, I have faced it once more.

This is what I have so far:

`objcopy --rename-sym` does not work for `.so`. (At least, now in 2014.)

Calling `System.loadLibrary()` or `System.load()` from `JNI_OnLoad()` does not work either (the libraries are reported as loaded in the logs, but their symbols do not appear), I did not try to fix it.

But you can
[make two native shared libraries calling each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688327/android-ndk-make-two-native-shared-libraries-calling-each-other), so you can make an extra library defining the function of interest, you (EDIT1:) can [rename that function in the original binary library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23211513/755804) (you have to preserve the hash function value), but you will have to *load()* or *loadLibrary()* the new library from Java.

EDIT2:

Now, how do we extend the dependency list of the calling library? We don't. In the import list of the calling library you find a library that you can recompile and extend, and in that library you define the new version of the renamed function. You do not need to care about the hash function and buckets if you change (in place) a library name in the dependency list.