# android NDK: objcopy --rename-sym does not work (need to rename a function in a .so file)

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, binutils, objcopy

I cannot get `objcopy --rename-sym` working.

In a new Android project, I have created the directory jni and the file stub.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "dlog.h"

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
DLOG("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ JNI_OnLoad ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
int myfunc() { return 0; }
```

the command `~/an/ndk-build -j 4` says:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libTest.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libTest.so
[armeabi] Install        : libTest.so => libs/armeabi/libTest.so
[x86] Install        : libTest.so => libs/x86/libTest.so
[mips] Install        : libTest.so => libs/mips/libTest.so
```

(There are links:

```
an -> ~/android-ndk-r9d/
ax -> android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
ay -> ~/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/
```

)

Then I do

```
~/ax/arm-linux-androideabi-objcopy --redefine-sym myfunc=ourfunc libTest.so libTest-x.so
```

and get an *identical* libTest-x.so. I, of course, tried `~/ay/*objcopy`, with the same result.
I get no error messages. And *myfunc()* is still there, and no *ourfunc()*.

***How do I rename a function in the .so file?***

Comment: I tried a similar test on a .so file without success.  However, I was able to rename a normal (vs dynamic) symbol in a .o file using the ndk objcopy.  So the issue may be that this is not supported for *dynamic symbols*.  http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2006-03/msg00005.html Suggests that this may not be supported in binutils in general - there someone tried to add it and failed.

Comment: If you can adjust your requirement to use a same-length replacement name, then `sed` might do the trick, unless there is some sort of mandatory sorting I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to rename a function is to change the name in place without changing the length and without changing the hash value.

Keeping the same hash value is a bit tricky, you have to understand how `elf_hash()` works::

*elfhash.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long
elf_hash(const unsigned char *name)
{
    unsigned long h = 0 , g ;
    while (*name)
    {
        h = ( h << 4 ) + * name ++ ;
        if (g = h & 0xf0000000) {
            h ^= g >> 24 ;
        }
        h &= ~g ;
    }
    return h ;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    char* name = argv[1];
    printf("[%s]\n",name);
    unsigned long hash = elf_hash(name);
    printf("0x%lx\n",hash);
    return 0;
}
```

[[EDIT: a newer version is at 
 https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/hosttools/elfhash.c 
(it finds a name with the same hash)
]]

`gcc` it, and the usage is:

```
$ ./a.out myFunc
[myFunc]
0x74ddc43
$ ./a.out myFums
[myFums]
0x74ddc43
$ ./a.out myFuoC # Note: a different hash value
[myFuoC]
0x74ddc33
$ ./a.out myFupC
[myFupC]
0x74ddc43
```

The relevant part of the ASCII table is:

```
  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? 
@ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O 
P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ 
` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o 
p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
```

Then either

```
sed s/myFunc/myFums/g <libStuff.so >libStufx.so
```

or a manual replace via `hexedit libStuff.so`.

Comment: But what about if the name length needs to increase?