# How can I specify output stuffs(like lib<xxx>.so)?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In `Android.mk`, how can I specify those `lib<xxx>.so`?

If I build a share library named `libfoo.so`, and it needs an external dynamic-linked library `libgnustl_shared.so`(may not exist in `obj/local/<arch>`), when I need to deliver our products(`libfoo.so` and `libgnustl_shared.so`). I must copy(install) both of them.

My `Android.mk` is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := igslib_rtc_timer
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../out/lib$(LOCAL_MODULE).so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := igslib_util
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../out/lib$(LOCAL_MODULE).a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := project

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    ../../main.cpp \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../../../interface ../../
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += igslib_util 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += igslib_rtc_timer

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

install:<libs>
    cp $^ <install_dir>
```

I need the variable **`<libs>`**, and it represents `libigslib_rtc_timer.so` and `libproject.so`. Any one knows?

Answer (score 0):

Please see

[Android NDK - make two native shared libraries calling each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688327/android-ndk-make-two-native-shared-libraries-calling-each-other)

[multiple (my and 3rd-party) native libraries in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363021/multiple-my-and-3rd-party-native-libraries-in-android-ndk)

[Using a prebuilt native binary in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144101/using-a-prebuilt-native-binary-in-android-app/27144612#27144612) (there are links)

Basically, to create multiple libraries you just concatenate the .mk files (or `include` them from the main .mk)

```
include abc.mk
include xyz.mk
```

and since each .mk starts with `CLEAR_VARS`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := abc
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

they do not affect each other. And everything found in `libs/` will go to the apk.

You will need to hard-code loading the libraries in the order that would resolve dependencies:

```
static { // calling from a static initializer is important!!!
    System.loadLibrary("abc"); // libabc.so does not depend on libxyz.so
    System.loadLibrary("xyz"); // libxyz.so can depend on libabc.so
}
```

UPDATE:

According to [multiple (my and 3rd-party) native libraries in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363021/multiple-my-and-3rd-party-native-libraries-in-android-ndk) ,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := random
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := librandom.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

will copy the existing library from the source location to *libs/*. You do not need to specify any installation steps, they always are the same: Android copies everything from the *lib/* folder in the apk (yes, this time lib, not libs) to your app's folder.

But there is one exception: this is true only for user applications, Android believes that for system applications (installed via placing them is /system/app on rooted devices and placed there by the firmware manufacturer on non-rooted devices) the libraries are installed by the app manufacturer (that is, either an installation script installs the libraries, or the application itself does this on its first run, or the library is a part of firmware).

Comment: I want to know how to specify them in *Android.mk*, not how to load it, thanks.

Comment: You found it in the links, didn't you? The first link if you build both libraries and the 2nd one if the library is pre-built; and for system libraries `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog` works for _liblog.so_.

Comment: I posted my `Android.mk` and emphasize the target, thanks.