# shared library(.so) in android studio could not to be found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an android project. For some features it needs some libraries, one of which is the `.so` library. I have installed `ndk`, and have moved the `.so` file to `jni/armeabi`, and in `gradle.properties` I have set `android.useDeprecatedNdk` to true, but I haven't seen any change and it throws an error that it cannot not find the `.so` file?

Answer (score 0):

Please see
[multiple (my and 3rd-party) native libraries in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363021/multiple-my-and-3rd-party-native-libraries-in-android-ndk) , maybe it will solve your problem. Please note that Android cannot combine libraries from the `libs/armeabi` and `libs/armeabi-v7a` directories.